# generate "X" close button with css3 gradient for bootstrap modal windows close button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gradient

I need to generate X close button with css3
I understand I need css3 gradients
but I do not know how to create what I want

the button what I need is here

```
http://demo.snstheme.com/sns-kunstore/index.php/
```

on the popup

please help me to create the button like this

I need this for bootstrap modal button with class close.

please help me to change default gradient with this.
but I need CSS not image.

please help...!!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'generate'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.circle-close {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 1px 3px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 1px 3px #ccc;
  box-shadow: -2px 1px 3px #ccc;
}

.circle-close:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="circle-close" >&times;</button>
```

Comment: no it is not what I want
it is only X
and I need with round black button

Comment: @giaberaia Hope the updated code does what you need